# iOS Multiple UIpickerView not showing Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, uipickerview

I have a hidden UIpickerView that should display a different Array depending on what button is pushed. The picker view shows up when the button is pushed but for some reason it doesn't show the Arrays in the picker view. I would be extremely grateful of any help!!!!

Here is the .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

#define GeoLocation TRUE // FALSE for no latitude/longitude information
#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PickerType) {
    CATEGORY_PICKER,
    LOCATION_PICKER,
    ORIGINATOR_PICKER,
    DESTINATION_PICKER,
    STATUS_PICKER
};

#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
#define kPICKER_TAG     101

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UIPickerView *picker;
    PickerType pickerType;
}
@synthesize nameTextField, emailTextField, dateTextField, timeTextField, blankTextField, blankbTextField, mlabelcategory, messageTextView, categoryTypeBtn;
@synthesize name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message, email, button;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        categoryTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Appetizers",@"Breakfast",@"Dessert",@"Drinks",
                         @"Main Dish/Entree", @"Salad", @"Side Dish", @"Soup", @"Snack",
                         @"Baby Food", @"Pet Food",nil];

        locationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue"
                         ,nil];

        originatorTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                           nil];


        destinationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                            nil];


        statusTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                       nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    nameTextField.text = nil;
    emailTextField.text = nil;
    dateTextField.text = nil;
    timeTextField.text = nil;
    blankTextField.text = nil;
    blankbTextField.text = nil;
    mlabelcategory.text = nil;
    messageTextView.text = nil;

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,400,160)];
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}


/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)eve
{
    picker.hidden = YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER:
            return [categoryTypes count];;
            break;
        case LOCATION_PICKER:
            return [locationTypes count];
            break;
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER:
            return [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        case DESTINATION_PICKER:
            return [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        case STATUS_PICKER:
            return [statusTypes count];
            break;
        default: return -1;
            break;
    }

}



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER:
            return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case LOCATION_PICKER:
            return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER:
            return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case DESTINATION_PICKER:
            return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case STATUS_PICKER:
            return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default: return nil;
            break;

    }
}




- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerType) {
        case CATEGORY_PICKER: {
            NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case LOCATION_PICKER: {

            NSString *locationType  = [locationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [locationTypeBtn setTitle:locationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;

        }
        case ORIGINATOR_PICKER: {
            NSString *originatorType  = [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [originatorTypeBtn setTitle:originatorType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case DESTINATION_PICKER: {
            NSString *destinationType  = [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [destinationTypeBtn setTitle:destinationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
        case STATUS_PICKER:{
            NSString *statusType  = [statusTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            [statusTypeBtn setTitle:statusType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
-(IBAction) showLocationTypePicker{

    pickerType = LOCATION_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];

}
-(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker{
    pickerType = CATEGORY_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showOriginatorTypePicker{
    pickerType = ORIGINATOR_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showDestinationTypePicker{
    pickerType = DESTINATION_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction) showStatusTypePicker{
    pickerType = STATUS_PICKER;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker reloadAllComponents];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma - getting info from the UI

//NSString *test = nil;


- (IBAction)checkData:(id)sender
{
    /*
     name = nameTextField.text;
     surname = surnameTextField.text;
     bornDate = bornDateTextField.text;
     address = addressTextField.text;
     zipCode = zipTextField.text;
     email = emailTextField.text;
     */

    //NSLog(@" Name: %@ \n Surname: %@ \n Date of Birth: %@ \n Address: %@ \n Post Code: %@ \n email: %@ \n", name, surname, bornDate, address, zipCode, email);

    unsigned int x,a = 0;
    NSMutableString *emailmessage; //stringa variabile
    emailmessage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @""]; //le stringhe mutabili vanno inizializzate in questo modo!


    for (x=0; x<7; x++)
    {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                if (nameTextField.text == nil) {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Name, "];
                    a=1;

                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (emailTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email Address, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (dateTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Date of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (timeTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Time of Near Miss, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                if (blankTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Post Code, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                if (blankbTextField.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Email, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            case 6:
                if (mlabelcategory.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Category, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (messageTextView.text == nil)
                {
                    [emailmessage appendString:@"Observation Description, "];
                    a=1;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    NSLog (@"Email Message: %@", emailmessage);

    if (a == 1) {

        NSMutableString  *popupError;
        popupError = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"Per inviare compilare i seguenti campi:  "];

        [popupError appendString:emailmessage]; //aggiungo i miei errori
        [popupError appendString: @" grazie della comprensione."]; //

        NSLog(@"%@", popupError);

        UIAlertView *chiamataEffettuata = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"ATTENTION" //titolo del mio foglio
                                           message:popupError
                                           delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, correggo" //bottone con cui si chiude il messaggio
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [chiamataEffettuata show]; //istanza per mostrare effettivamente il messaggio
    }

    else
    {
        name = nameTextField.text;
        emailaddress = emailTextField.text;
        date = dateTextField.text;
        time = timeTextField.text;
        blank = blankTextField.text;
        blankb = blankbTextField.text;
        category = mlabelcategory.text;
        message = messageTextView.text;


        NSMutableString *nearmissreport;
        nearmissreport = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<br><br> <b>Name:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Date of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Time of Near Miss:</b> %@ <br> <b>Post Code:</b> %@ <br> <b>Email Address:</b> %@ <br> <b>Category:</b> %@ <br><b>Observation Description:</b> %@ <br>", name, emailaddress, date, time, blank, blankb, category, message];

        NSLog(@"Near Miss Report: %@", nearmissreport);

        NSMutableString *testoMail;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: nearmissreport];

        NSLog(@"%@", testoMail);


        //MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        MFMailComposeViewController  *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController  alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject: name];

        // Set up the recipients.
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"paul.haddell@bbmmjv.com",nil];

        //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
        //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
        //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        // Attach an image to the email.
        //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
        //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

        // Fill out the email body text.
        //NSMutableString *emailBody;
        testoMail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@", testoMail];

        [picker setMessageBody:testoMail isHTML:YES]; //HTML!!!!!!

        // Present the mail composition interface.
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}


// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Mandare email
/*
 - (void)sendMail:(NSMutableString*)testoMail{

 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [picker setSubject:@"Reclutamento pompieri"];

 // Set up the recipients.
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"reda.bousbah@gmail.com",nil];
 //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil];
 //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"four@example.com",nil];

 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
 //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
 //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

 // Attach an image to the email.
 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ipodnano" ofType:@"png"];
 //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
 //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ipodnano"];

 // Fill out the email body text.
 NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

 // Present the mail composition interface.
 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


 }
 */



#pragma mark - methods to control the keyboard

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender //method for resign the keyboard when the background is tapped
{
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [dateTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [timeTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [blankbTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [mlabelcategory resignFirstResponder];
    [messageTextView resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"done button pressed");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You should do some debugging to narrow the problem down (and post less code).  Step through the code in the debugger.  Check variable values.  Add NSLogs.  If the picker view is not showing the arrays, confirm that the arrays are getting initialized (eg. is initWithNibName actually executing).  Confirm that the picker view delegate methods are getting called and confirm what values they are seeing for the arrays.

Comment: Nothing comes up in the debug window when I run this app. I have no idea why its not working. I have a great example which works fine when I then try to create the same app as a completely new app it doesn't show anything in the array. But doesn't come up with any indication as to why.

Comment: Debugging is not just for when the app crashes and writes something by itself in the debug console.  You can also use it to trace problems where there is no crash.  Learn how to use breakpoints, step through the code line by line.  At a minimum, you should be able to put NSLogs at critical points to confirm things are happening the way you think.